# I there is way to burn ERC223 tokens like we do to ECR20 token?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

but as far as i know  alike ECR20, ECR223 token cant be send to an address without having tokenFallback() do we have another way around to burn the ERC223 tokens?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can burn the token by deleting the allocated token to the particular address and subtracting the equal value from the total supply.

```
 function burn(uint256 _value) public {
require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
// no need to require value <= totalSupply, since that would imply the
// sender's balance is greater than the totalSupply, which *should* be an assertion failure

address burner = msg.sender;
balances[burner] = balances[burner].sub(_value);
totalSupply_ = totalSupply_.sub(_value);
Burn(burner, _value);
}
```